# the set of all composite numbers and its properties

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let A be the set of all composite numbers and let d be such a number that for every element **a** of A, **a**+d is also a composite number. I want to show that such a number d cannot exist, but especially in view of the fact that some odd number are also composite have trouble doing that.

Comment: Not "a set", "the set".

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem on primes in an arithmetic progression says the arithmetic progression $(d+1)^2 + k\cdot d$ contains infinitely many primes. Unless, of course, $d = 0$ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result does not hold if $d=0$.

We will show that for any $d\gt 0$, there is a composite $a$ such that $a+d$ is prime.

Take a large number $N$. For definiteness let $N=d+2$. Then the numbers $N!+2$, $N!+3$, and so on up to $N!+N$ are all composite. The composites may continue for a while beyond $N!+N$. Let $p$ be the **smallest** prime $\gt N!+N$. Then $p-d$ is composite. That is our $a$.

**Remark:** For negative $d$, go backwards from $N!$ to the largest prime $\lt N!+N$.

Comment: We argue for positive $d$ (negative is similar). Recall that we chose $N$ big, say bigger than $d+2$. If $p$ is the smallest prime $\gt N!+N$, then all the numbers from $N!+2$ to $p-1$ are composite. There are at least $N-1$ such numbers, since the smallest prime $\gt N!+N$ is $\ge N!+N+1$. Since $N\gt d+2$, the number $p-d$ falls in this group of composites.

Comment: I get it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. The proof relies on the standard argument that there are arbitrarily large gaps between consecutive primes.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $d>0$ is such a number. The set $S=\{\,4+kd\mid k\ge0\,\}$ contains infinitely many primes. Let $p$ be the smallest such prime. Then $a=p-d$ is composite and $a+d$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $d$ is such a number. We know that there are arbitrary gaps of composite numbers. Assume that $N+1,N+2,\ldots,N+k$ are composite numbers such that $N, N+k+1$ are primes and $k>d$. Now derive a contradiction.